# How can i append a React Component to React ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I need to append as a child react component to ref that i pass by redux. I can't figure out way to do that. Is that even possible?

Comment: seems like a code smell to me

Comment: It's for animated message that's shows up when user clicks on button. It's my pet project and i still learning react. For now i came up with some another pathetic code monstrosity, that uses portals, but i really disgusted by it 's existence. At least it's working... somehow.